# Capturing layoutComplete event with angular-masonry

Tags: angularjs, masonry

I am using [angular-masonry](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry/) for one of my projects, and have it set up like so...

```
<div id="tile_container" masonry preserve-order column-width="340" reload-on-show masonry-options="{ transitionDuration: '0.2s', gutter: 0 }">
    <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" class="masonry-brick">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, it takes a couple seconds for AngularJS to fetch the items that are in my `tiles` object and then for Masonry to lay them out. How can I capture a `layoutComplete` event from masonry using this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look this:

```
var $grid = angular.element('#tile_container'); 
$grid.masonry( 'on', 'layoutComplete',
     function( msnryInstance, laidOutItems ) {
        console.log('layoutComplete');
     } );
```

Comment: When I place this code inside my controller, I get an error: `cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call 'on'`

Comment: Well, I can get it working, but not properly. Either layoutComplete is emitted multiple times, or just once when the page loads - this may be because I'm dynamically adding bricks to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,

```
$scope.$on('masonry.created', function (evt, element) {
        element.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', function(instance, items) {
           console.log(instance);
        });
    });
```

It's working for me.